# what is practical differences between flush, write() and fflush()?

Tags: c, system-calls, flush, fflush

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44191304/what-does-flushing-the-database-mean-also-with-flash), the answer said

Flushing: To sync the temporary state of your application data with the permanent state of the data (in a database, or on disk).

I think that the flush is executed when some buffer is written to an i/o device (like disk) by the `write()` system call.

So it seems that a data writing to a device with `write()` and the data flushing to the device are to do the same things.

If so, can I say that the flushing a data with `fflush()` and the writing the data with `write()` are completely same?

Comment: Think of `flush` as meaning **commit**; you can write as much as you want, but unless you commit those changes then they'll remain in-memory and won't be reflected by the actual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's do the obvious thing:

[fflush](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush)

> For output streams (and for update streams on which the last operation was output), writes any unwritten data from the stream's buffer to the associated output device.

The C Standard doesn't state how the data is written to the output device. On Posix systems, most likely via [write](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html), other systems might have different (similar) interfaces.

Conceptually speaking, a flush will use the underlying write primitive to transmit the data from the buffer to the output device.

**In short:**

- `fflush()` the same as `write()` -> No.
- `fflush()` uses `write()` -> Yes, most likely.
- `fflush()` and `write()` ensures the data to be written to the output device -> Yes.